# Is it possible to run a .app that relies on Java on Yosemite without installing Java for OS X 2014-001 and to use JRE 8 directly?

Tags: java, macos, eclipse-rcp, rcp, osx-yosemite

I have a Java app (built on Eclipse RCP) packaged as a .app but running it produces the message:

> To open “XYZ” you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime.
>
> Click “More Info…” to visit the legacy Java SE 6 download website.

Where the *More Info...* button leads to the Apple Support page: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

I'm assuming it should be possible to **install JRE 8** (u25 being current, u20 fixed a Yosemite install issue I believe) **thereby satisfying the Java requirement** and allowing the app to run, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Is this install effectively mandatory (**legacy** probably sounding scary to the average user) to get Java working on Yosemite?

Will apps use JRE 8 if installed after *Java for OS X 2014-001* is installed?

This is driving me nuts as I'm wondering if my Info.plist has something bad in it, but I see the issue with other Java .app software too.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems since the Equinox Launcher was changed you can't start an RCP app with JRE 8; it does work with the JDK 8 however! Trying to use the JRE causes this error message:

"The JVM shared library "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/../lib/server/libjvm.dylib"
does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol"

See: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=449428

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Java versions can coexist and offer functionality afforded by the earlier version.  I tested it with the attempted launch of an app failing, then succeeding after the legacy install.

To be completely on the safe side, any further info in this regard should be referred to Java.